# Accessing a private member variable of an object created in static function of corresponding class does not lead to error. why?

Tags: c++

I dont get error when I access a private member variable of an object that was created in static function of that class. Consider below code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
class fruit{
    private: int a;
    public:
             fruit(){
                 a = 2;
                 b = 3;
             }
             static void set(){
                 fruit f;
                 printf("%d",f.a); // no error; why? (a is still in private)
             }
};

void call(){
   fruit f;
   printf("%d",f.a); // error: a is private; works as I expect
}
```

All I can understand is when a new object is created in static function of that corresponding class, you can even access private variables as public mode? but doesn't this break access specifiers concept? Or is there something Iam understanding wrong. No book pointed me this statement.

All these days I was under assumption that to access private data, you need object and non static method but after compiling the above code I was wrong. It seems like you dont need non static method. I tried even compiling the same on codepad.org http://codepad.org/H06FyRLL gave me o/p as 2. Kindly help me is this valid? and could anyone suggest some good tutorials to learn such hidden secrets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access private members of any object of that type (not just `*this`) from all members and friends of the class. That includes static member functions.

> could anyone suggest some good tutorials

[The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242)

Answer (score 0):

Because `set` is a static member function of your class.
Consequently it has access to all the namespace of your class.

Comment: What does namespace mean?

Comment: the wikipedia article is explaining this word in a thorough manner: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace   Good reading !

Comment: Ironically the link doesn't explain "namespace of a class" in C++

Answer (score 0):

A static function is a non-member function of a class - consider it as `friend` of the class. A friend function has exclusive access to all members of a class - right?